# Related to SOM Tool Box

Tags: matlab, som

I need a help related to som tool box. Here is the question.
"we have 100 input records(which belongs to two classes) how do we know from SOMToolbox output whether a particular input say number 35 is clustered as class 1 or class 2, can we finalize it from u-matrix or is there any other file , we want to final the accuracy from the SOM output"

please help me if you know the answer and waiting for your suggestions

Comment: if this is MATLAB related, please tag as such

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the no of data to be trained, or you can stop the training after your limit. One can see the changes on mesh live as the data are being processed in som-toolbox in matlab.